# Creating new instance from Class with constructor parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I have situation where my Java class needs to create a ton of certain kind of objects. I would like to give the name of the class of the objects that are created as a parameter. In addition, I need to give the created class a parameter in its constructor. I have something like

```
class Compressor {

    Class ccos;

    public Compressor(Class ccos) {
        this.ccos = ccos;
    }

    public int getCompressedSize(byte[] array) {
        OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // the following doesn't work because ccos would need os as its constructor's parameter
        OutputStream cos = (OutputStream) ccos.newInstance();
        // ..
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I could remedy this?

Edit:

This is part of a research project where we need to evaluate the performance of multiple different compressors with multiple different inputs. `Class ccos` is a compressed `OutputStream` either from Java's standard library, Apache Compress Commons or lzma-java.

Currently I have the following which appears to work fine. Other ideas are welcome.

```
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream compressedOut = (OutputStream) ccos.getConstructor(OutputStream.class).newInstance(os);
final InputStream sourceIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
```

Comment: Why do you need to tell `Compressor` what kind of objects to create? What kinds of classes will be used here?

Comment: Have you considered using an abstract factory for this rather than hacking it with reflections?

Comment: I guess the question is complete now. Any additional information is perhaps for another question.

Comment: It would be great if somebody could write a proper answer based on all the information above so I could accept it.

Comment: @Ihahne - the additional information does not seem directly related to this question. And there is no question there at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `Class.getConstructor(paramsTypes...)` method and call `newInstance(..)` on the constructor. In your case:

```
Compressor.class.getConstructor(Class.class).newInstance(Some.class);
```

Comment: I think you mean `Compressor.class.getConstructor(Class.class).newInstance(someparameter);`

Comment: @lhahne well, since your parameter is of type `Class`, it can be `Some.class`

Comment: Simple example:  CreateObjects is a java class, Can invoke newInstance by the below way without any arguments for constructor.


    `CreateObjects obj2 = CreateObjects.class.getConstructor().newInstance();`

Answer (score 4):

Using Spring ClassUtils and BeanUtils classes you can avoid dealing with those tedious exceptions that is Spring handling for you :

```
Constructor<Car> constructor = ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable(Wheels.class, Etc.class);
Car car = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(constructor, new Wheels(), new Etc());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get to the relevant `Constructor` object (e.g. via `Class.getConstructors` or `Class.getConstructor`) and then call `constructor.newInstance`, giving it the arguments it requires.

Answer (score 0):

An example you can use is as follows:
lets say conn is a connection to the database.

```
Class[] btarray = { conn.getClass() };      
try {
   if (classname != null) {
      pmap = (Mapper) Class.forName(classname)
                           .getConstructor(btarray)
                           .newInstance(
                              new Object[] { conn }
                           );
   }
} catch (Throwable x) {
   x.printStackTrace(Log.out);
}
```

btarray allows you to pass in arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Compresor<T> {
    private Class<? extends T> clazz;
    Compresor(final Class<? extends T> cls){
        this.clazz = cls
    }
}
```